# Typescipt DataPoint type

Tags: typescript, types

I'm trying to achieve a simple thing (IMO), but it seems I'm not enough experienced with Typescript.

I'd like to define a type that pass following expressions:

```
const dp: DataPoint = [1, 2];
const dp2: DataPoint = [1, 2, 3];
const dps: DataPoints = [[1, 2], [2, 3]];
const dps2: DataPoints = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]];
```

I did this:

```
export type DataPoint<T = number, D = number> = [number, T, D?];
export type DataPoints<T = number, D = number> = DataPoint<T, D>[];
```

and tried many other ways to do it, but in the end the result type of all of them consists two generics:
`DataPoint<number, number>` or `DataPoints<number, number>`.
Is there a way to infer `never` from the `dp` example and have `DataPoint<number>` instead of `<DataPoint<number, number>`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use tuples to keep things simple:

```
type DataPoint = 
  | [number, number]
  | [number, number, number]
  | [[number, number], [number, number]]
  | [[number, number, number], [number, number, number]];

const dp: DataPoint = [1, 2];
const dp2: DataPoint = [1, 2, 3];
const dps: DataPoint = [[1, 2], [2, 3]];
const dps2: DataPoint = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]];
```

Or if you want to keep it a bit more flexible using arrays:

```
type DataPoint = 
  | [number, number]
  | [number, number, number]
  | Array<[number, number]>
  | Array<[number, number, number]>
```

Comment: I've just realized that If I remove ``DataPoint`` and use ``export type DataPoints<T = number, D = number> = [number, T, D][] | [number, T][];`` it infers types correctly. why is that?
Thanks anyway for adding this answer!

Comment: `export type DataPoints<T = number, D = number> = [number, T, D][] | [number, T][];` is the same as `Array<[number, number, number]> | Array<[number, number]>;`. It is an union type of an array containing either a tuple with `[number, number]` or `[number, number, number]`, which works for `dps` and `dps2`

Comment: Not necessarily as ``T`` and ``D`` can be anything, not only a ``number``.

Comment: That's true. Just an example due to your default values both being `number`.